# Performance issue of GLImageProcessing re-implemented with OpenGL ES 2 shaders

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I re-implemented Apple's [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) with OpenGL ES 2 shaders. The effects are perfect but the performance of the Sharpness filter is not as good — it runs only at 20 FPS.

The shader code is simple:

1. Pass 0 for horizontal blur.
2. Pass 1 for vertical blur.
3. Pass 2 to mix the blur texture with the original texture.

Basically, the texture mix in Pass 2 is the cause of slowness since Pass 0 and Pass 1 are only done once and do not contribute to the bad performance.

How can I improve the performance?

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying highp vec2 v_texCoord;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord1;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord2;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord1_;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord2_;

uniform mat4 u_modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform lowp int u_pass;

const highp float blurSizeH = 1.0 / 320.0;
const highp float blurSizeV = 1.0 / 480.0;

void main()
{
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
    if (u_pass == 0) {
        v_texCoord1 = a_texCoord + vec2(1.3846153846 * blurSizeH, 0.0);
        v_texCoord1_ = a_texCoord - vec2(1.3846153846 * blurSizeH, 0.0);
        v_texCoord2 = a_texCoord + vec2(3.2307692308 * blurSizeH, 0.0);
        v_texCoord2_ = a_texCoord - vec2(3.2307692308 * blurSizeH, 0.0);
    } else if (u_pass == 1) {
        v_texCoord1 = a_texCoord + vec2(0.0, 1.3846153846 * blurSizeV);
        v_texCoord1_ = a_texCoord - vec2(0.0, 1.3846153846 * blurSizeV);
        v_texCoord2 = a_texCoord + vec2(0.0, 3.2307692308 * blurSizeV);
        v_texCoord2_ = a_texCoord - vec2(0.0, 3.2307692308 * blurSizeV);
    }

    gl_Position = u_modelViewProjectionMatrix * a_position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord1;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord2;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord1_;
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord2_;

uniform lowp int u_pass;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_degenTexture;
uniform mediump mat4 u_filterMat;

void main()
{
    if (u_pass == 0) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord) * 0.2270270270;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord1) * 0.3162162162;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord1_) * 0.3162162162;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord2) * 0.0702702703;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord2_) * 0.0702702703;
    } else if (u_pass == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord) * 0.2270270270;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord1) * 0.3162162162;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord1_) * 0.3162162162;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord2) * 0.0702702703;
        gl_FragColor += texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord2_) * 0.0702702703;
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = u_filterMat * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord) + (mat4(1.0) - u_filterMat) * texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is really simple. The cause of bad performance is matrix-vector multiplication:

```
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_degenTexture;
uniform lowp float u_filterValue;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = u_filterMat * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord) + (mat4(1.0) - u_filterMat) * texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord);
}
```

I initially wrote my code using matrix this way so that all my filters could share the same color mixing code. Now that I learned the lesson, I simply go back to write filter specific code and use scalar operations as much as possible:

```
varying highp vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_degenTexture;
uniform lowp float u_filterValue;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = u_filterValue * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord) + (1.0 - u_filterValue) * texture2D(u_degenTexture, v_texCoord);
}
```

Now it is awesome 60 fps!

Never thought it was such a naive issue, but it is.

Answer (score 1):

Before you continue with this, may I suggest you take a look at my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) project? I have several hand-optimized sharpening effects in there, including the unsharp mask you're attempting here. I also make it reasonably easy to pull in image and video sources.

To your specific question, there are a couple of reasons why your shader is running slower than expected. The first is that you are using branching within your fragment shader. This kills performance on iOS devices, and should be avoided if at all possible. If you really need to have different conditions for different passes, split these apart into separate shader programs and swap the programs out as needed rather than using a uniform for control flow.

I'm also not sure that writing to gl_FragColor repeatedly is the fastest thing you can do here. I'd use a lowp or mediump intermediate color variable, add your Gaussian components to that, and then write the final result to gl_FragColor when done.

I do see that you've moved your sampling offset calculations to the vertex shader, and then passed those offsets into the fragment shader, which is a good thing that people usually miss. Once you implement the above tweaks (or give my framework a try to see how I handle this), you should get much better results from your filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation and sorry for the belated response. Just I guessed, I can not see any meaningful boost in performance after splitting the shader into 3 shaders instead of using 3 branches in a single shader. Neither is intermediate color variable helpful. I think today's hardware already does good enough optimization for simple branching and multi-writting so these are no longer bottlenecks. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Or maybe as an expert you could see why OpenGL ES 1.0 inherently has better performance then OpenGL ES 2.0 for this kind of texture composition. I have no experience in OpenGL ES 1.0 programming so I have no idea.

Comment: @an0 - I'm not sure how you're doing your benchmarking of your shaders, but avoiding conditionals and splitting your shader into separate programs has a huge effect on every iOS GPU I've worked with. It's usually on the order of 3-10X speedups when removing conditionals, so no, they aren't optimized for branching at all. Also OpenGL ES 1.1 does not have inherently better performance than 2.0 for equivalent operations, because 1.1 on 2.0-compatible iOS hardware simply uses built-in shaders to replicate the fixed-function pipeline.

Comment: If removing branching didn't speed up your shader, I'd look elsewhere for your performance bottlenecks, because that should have made a huge difference. It may be that you're not fragment-limited at all and need to optimize some other part of your rendering operations. Again, you can pull up the sample applications in my GPUImage framework and see how fast the blurs operate there.

Comment: I tried Gaussian Blur in FilterShowcase. Its performance is on par with mine(18 fps VS 20 fps). I also read its shader code and found that we use different approaches. You use 2-pass sampling and adjust the blurness by adjusting "blur offset". I use 3-pass sampling. The first 2 are the same as yours except they use a fixed "blur offset" and the last pass is mixing the result of 2-pass blur sampling and the original texture, and the blurness is adjusted by adjusting the mixing matrix in the 3rd pass sampling. Mine can both blur and sharp. GLImageProcessing kicks both our asses. Check it out.

Comment: And there is really no performance difference that I can tell in branching-in-shader VS split-shaders. I'm inclined to believe there is but I just can't see it.

Comment: @an0 - GLImageProcessing isn't using a true Gaussian blur, though. They're rotating and offsetting the image twice, then using interpolation to blend these offset images with the original. They sample roughly 17 texels in a three-radius, where both of our blurs are true Gaussians that work over a larger number of texel samples. You sample a 5x5 texel area (25 texels), where I go over a 9x9 area (81 texels), so we're not really comparing apples to apples here. My GPUImageFastBlurFilter does a Gaussian over a 9x9 region using interpolation to only sample 5 texels per pass, for example.

Comment: @an0 - Also, looking at framerate can be a poor judge of actual performance, particularly with something like the FilterShowcase, because the iOS camera is capped at a 30 FPS framerate by itself, and will dip down to 15 FPS in low light conditions. This is why I log the frame render times to the console in that application, because those are a better measure of performance than anything tied to the camera and its variable input framerate.

Comment: I modified SimpleImageFilter to use Gaussian Blur and the same image that I'm using and got the same fps as mine. At least now I'm quite sure that it is not the case that my code is bad and branching-in-shader VS split-shaders is really not a cause of performance issue.

Comment: I figured out. It is just because of matrix-vector multiplication. See my answer for details. You are really helpful along the way. The idea of splitting the shader into smaller ones is along the lines of that of writing filter-specific shaders instead of a reusable general one. This experience taught me a lesson that good performance comes first before good software engineering in graphic programming. And your nudging me to to GPUImage gave me the chance to finally check out your awesome code —— I stared it on Github long time ago and just didn't want to read it being lazy. Thanks a lot!